# how much is a in this hyperbola equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

we were given by our teacher today this equation: $(y^2/9)-(x^2/16)=1$ How much is a in this equation according to hyperbola equation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but our eclipse equations may not be the same as yours.  You can't expect us to be in the same class as you.

Answer (score 2):

In this equation the $y$ axis is along the vertical center of the symmetry of the hyperbola. So it can be written as 
$$
\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1
$$
so $a=3, b=4$

Comment: Thanks for answering, that's what I needed